# how can I pass props to child props? (vue.js)

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Hi I'm making vue application and What I want to do is there's parentsComponent which has ChildOne and ChildTwo, the data is getting from same dataArray but childTwo has multiple data. and childTwo has childOneComponent inside. but I want to passed the data to ChildTwo from ParentsComponent and give it to ChildOne again. 
is it possible?

ParentsComponent.vue

```
<template>
<ChildOneComponent :data="NewsData">
<ChildTwoComponent :data="NewsData.sports">
</template>
```

ChildOneComponent.vue

```
<div>
{{data.title}}
</div>
```

ChildTwoComponent.vue

```
<ChildOneComponent></ChildOneComponent>
```

Comment: For starters, you cannot have two root elements in the template. In second place, you say the `ChildOneComponent` appears **both** in the parent as well as inside the `ChildTwoComponent`?

Comment: to clarify. childOne is inside childTwo and parentsComponent? and parent compoent also have childTwo?

Comment: @Evan yes your right. ParentsComponent has ChildOne and ChildTwo. and ChildTwo has ChildOne.

Comment: @ffflabs yes your right. ChildOneComponent  is in both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be as below. You will have to pass the whole Newsdata object to your ChildTwoComponent as you are rendering ChildOneComponent from it.

You can update your template rendering of ChildTwoComponent accordingly.

ParentsComponent.vue

```
<template>
   <div>
      <ChildOneComponent :data="NewsData">
      <ChildTwoComponent :data="NewsData">
   </div>
</template>
```

ChildTwoComponent.vue

```
<ChildOneComponent :data="NewsData"></ChildOneComponent>
```

Comment: Ensure you're receiving the data inside the props hook in the `ChildOneComponent` and `ChildTwoComponent`: `props: ['data']`

Comment: @can u explain bit more please?